# How to implement fifo with conditions in C# and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, winforms

I have selected multiple datarows with same product name, price and quantity and sorted them according to their primary key values in datatable. But when I decrease stock quantity, it decreases from all the rows. I want my code to check stock quantity according to user quantity entered in textbox and decrease it from FIRST ROW ONLY. This is what I have been able to do so far. apologies in advance for bad formatting I am new to programming and stackoverflow.

The data table has columns

```
Item_Name, Item_Quantity, Item_Price.
```

Code:

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from stock_recieve where Item_Name like'" + comboBoxitem.Text + "'order by [Bill No] asc";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        // DataRow row = dt.Select("Item_Quantity").FirstOrDefault();
        dt.Rows[0]["Item_Quantity"]=;

        int qty = 0;
        string pname = "";

        qty = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Item_Quantity"].ToString());
        qty = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxqty.Text);

        pname = dr["Item_Name"].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd6 = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd6.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd6.CommandText = "update stock_recieve set Item_Quantity=Item_Quantity-" + qty + "where Item_Name ='" + pname.ToString() + "'";

        cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    //MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully");
}
```

Comment: FYI - Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  Always use parameterized queries in your code.

Comment: Your UPDATE sql command will update all records with Item_Name matching pname - after selecting the top record, your UPDATE record should use the "Bill No" in the where clause (possibly combined with pname) if there can be more than 1 row with the Bill No.

Comment: Thanks for parameterized query ill use it in my code.

Comment: PaulF update by Bill No is a good suggestion but can I use FirstorDefault() or any other method to get the first row of Bill No from this datatable foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows).

Comment: Remark: keeping amounts in a stock record and decreasing (updating) an amount field while doing stock mutations is actually bad practice. Better organize your stock transactions in a second table. When totals are needed, join the stock records with  the transactions for every stock item type. Total over transaction amounts: The stock transaction record contains a negative amount for take out, a positive for takein... Things can be kept immutable,  And it ensures traceability, because all stock transactions are kept.

Answer (score 3):

Just  use `top 1` on your select query . Also using SQL parameters is very important. Try like:

```
...
cmd.CommandText = "select TOP 1 * from stock_recieve where Item_Name like @name order by [Bill No] asc";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =comboBoxitem.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Comment: the like is actually an equals (same in original) - just wondering if this is intentional or should there be %% surrounding it?

Comment: @johnMcTighe I also wanted to add the wildcards but left it as it is in the Question

Comment: If I use select Top 1 * on my query than it wont load the rest of the same product names, for example in my table chicken has been saved more than once with its quantity and price changed to implement fifo.

Comment: There should be a % surrounding it with like but I just could not get it to work with the code, it would'nt give me the all product names according to comboBox, I don't know why, removing it justt worked.